# Epsteins zeta function

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

The Epstein's zeta function is: $Z(Y,s)=\underset{0\neq a\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}}{\sum}(a^{t}Ya)^{-s}$, where Y is a positive symmetric difinite $n \times n$ matrix.

- Why does it converges when $\sigma > \frac{n}{2}$ (where $s=\sigma+it$)?
- let $\theta (Y,t)=\underset{0\neq a\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}}{\sum}exp(-\pi (a^{t}Ya)t)$.

  how can I proof the following:

  $\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)Z(Y,s)=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{s-1}[\theta(Y,t)-1]dt$?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-bt}dt =  \int_0^\infty (u/b)^{s-1} e^{-u} \frac{du}{b}= b^{-s} \Gamma(s)$ and can you show the convergence for $\sigma > n/2$ when $Y$ is the identity matrix ? (compare the sum with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n, \|x\| > 1} \|x\|^{-2s}dx$)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I proved it when $Y$ is the identity matrix but why is this enough? (is it somehow because $Y$ is real symmetric and therefore diagonalizable?)
did you solved the second question?

Comment: Look at the change of variable $x = B u$, $\|x\|^2 = x^\top x = u^\top B^\top B u= u^\top Y u$

Comment: Great! (just to make sure I understood: $B$ is the matrix from the Cholesky decomposition of $Y$, and the integral is exactly the same but multiplied by $det(B)$ right? :))

did you solved this: $\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)Z(Y,s)=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{s-1}[\theta(Y,t)-1]dt$?

Comment: $Y$ is diagonalizable so $Y = P D P^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, it is symmetric so $P^\top = P^{-1}$, and positive so $D$ has strictly positive diagonal entries. $B = Q D^{1/2} P^\top$ with $Q$ your preferred orthogonal matrix. Cholesky decomposition is obtained with a particular $Q$ making $B$ uper triangular. My 1st comment contains the solution to your other question.